# Embedding an HTML page keeps redirecting me?

Tags: html, embed, frame

I'm attempting to write a simple html doc to automatically refresh every 5 seconds.  However, I want to embed a web page into this.  I've tried embed tags, object tags, and iframe tags.  However, each time the page refreshes I am automatically redirected to the page that I am trying to embed.  My current code version is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MEETME REFRESHER</title>
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);
function reloadIFrame()
{
    document.frames["meetframe"].location.reload();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.meetme.com/apps/home" name="meetframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I using incorrect tags or is there something obvious that I'm missing here?
I have been on about 10 sites similar to W3Schools, however to no avail.  Could it be an issue localized to Chrome?  I remember doing something similar to this back in school, though using Internet Explorer.  Any help or input is much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding some doctype header.. like: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I've never used doctypes, I never thought they were entirely necessary so I'm not sure what they do, how to use them, or when.

Comment: Trust me.. they are :) the one i provided is html5 doctype.

Comment: But then which tag should I use to embed the web page?

Comment: i just added
    <iframe src="http://www.meetme.com/apps/home"></iframe>
but the same problem occured, i was redirected to the src.  Could it be my meta tag doing it?

Comment: Refresh the page with javascript.

Comment: I updated my code above, the same problem is still present.  I'm being redirected almost immediately.

Comment: Try with another browser. Maybe some security feature..

Comment: i used a meta refresh using 'inspect element' in chrome and it did refresh, im thinking its just the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Using `sandbox` attribute of an iframe. Source and more information [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MEETME REFRESHER</title>
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000);
function reloadIFrame()
{
    var fr=document.getElementById('meetframe');
    if(fr!=null) document.getElementById("container").removeChild(fr);
    var iframehtml="<iframe sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms' src='http://www.meetme.com/apps/home' id='meetframe'></iframe>";
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=iframehtml;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id = "container">
        <iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://www.meetme.com/apps/home" name = "meetframe" id="meetframe"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks!! The only problem I have is that the width gets massively reduced (i added width/height to be 100% in the iframe in the div tag) after refreshing.  i added the height/weidth=100% in the function part but then the refreshing does not occur.  is there a way to make it not scale down?

regardless, you sir, are my savior

Comment: add CSS styling to the iframe. `#meetframe{ width:100%; height:100%; }`. Should work.